# When the scalpel is applied

Tags: riddle, word, limerick

What word is hidden in the following Limerick?

```
 See my first when the scalpel's applied
 In my final, a pronoun is spied
    My middle is meant
    To be readily bent
 And my all, like a serpent, can slide.
```

Comment: Meh, thought I had it... lost my thought though. Good one

Comment: This is driving me crazy! I will be dreaming of snakes and scalpels tonight.

Comment: Can you clarify the meaning of the last line? Is it "like a serpent can slide" describing how a serpent slides, or is it "can slide like a serpent" describing an object which moves like a serpent?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Slither

See my first when the scalpel's applied

> Slit made when a cut from the scalpel

In my final, a pronoun is spied

> Her, feminine pronoun

My middle is meant to be readily bent

> lithe, synonymous with agile

And my all, like a serpent can slide.